# One Click Table of Contents in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I would like to create a table of contents in Google docs that would take only one click for the user to get to where the hyperlink is pointing rather than the two clicks that it seems to require (click on the TOC words and then click on the hyperlink).  Is this possible in Google docs?

Answer (score 2):

Requiring two clicks to follow a link in a Google Doc is a property of the Editing and Suggesting modes of the Docs editor. Basically, it does this so that you can insert the caret (typing "cursor") into the middle of hyperlinked text using your mouse without automatically taking you to the link's destination.

Your users will be able to follow TOC links in one click so long as they are viewing the document in Viewing mode (in the editor) or in published HTML form. (For information on how to publish a document, check out [this Docs editors Help article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en).)